# How Can I Make My Website Look Better on Mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this website. It looks out exactly how I wanted on PC, so I got some hosting service and domain and I tried opening it on my phone and it looks absolutely ridiculous: [image]

I read somewhere that adding this line should fix this problem **  ** but i didnt :/ (i am new to programming so have mercy on me).

This is my code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<title>Dream Car</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Author" content="Marko Misic">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
  .tabela{
    z-index: -1
  }
  body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("auto.jpg");

  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
h3{
  font-size: 250%; color:black; border-bottom:rgb(222, 78, 0);    
}
.ekipatext{
  text-align: center; margin-left: 100px  
}
.bg.image{
  background-image: url(auto.jpg);  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
.mySlides {display: none}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Navigacija -->>
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dream_car_ng/" class="w3-bar-item w3-padding-large w3-hover-red w3-hide-small "><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">POČETNA</a>
    <a href="#band" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">EKIPA</a>
    <a href="#tour" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">SHOP</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">KONTAKT</a>
    
     <p class="">
    
    
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dream_car_ng/" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-red w3-hide-small w3-right"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Navigacija za male ekrane -->
<div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-black w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-top" style="margin-top:46px">
  <a href="#band" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">EKIPA</a>
  <a href="#tour" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">SHOP</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">KONTAKT</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">SHOP</a>
</div>

<!-- Sadrzaj -->
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:2000px;margin-top:46px">

  <!-- Slideshow ako mi se digne patka da ubacim -->
  <div class=" w3-display-container w3-center">
    <img src="dreamcar1.jpg.jpg" style="width: 100%"  style="height:%">
    
 <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64  " style="max-height: 200px;background-color: black; max-width: 100%  " id="dream car">  
  <h3 class=" w3-wide"><img src="logodreamcar.png"></h3>
  </div>
<div class="w3-black w3-conten w3-border">
  <h4>
   <iframe width="85%" height="900" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B7gRS74ODsM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </h4>
  <!-- Ekipa -->
  <div class="w3-container w3-black w3-content w3-center  w3-padding-64" style="max-width:100%" id="band">
  
    <h2 class="w3-wide">EKIPA</h2>
    <p class="w3-opacity"><i>We love cars</i></p>
    <div class="ekipatext">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad a da da d ad ad a d ad a d ad a wd aw dw d awd aw dwa aw d awd wad  nd b f  vhudfsg dfijsg ishfdg dsfg hdsfug hdsfiug bhudfsg ufds giuhdfsogh usdhfg uisdhfg uisdhfgi hsfdiughi usdhfgiuhsdf iughdsiuf hguidsfhg uidshf giuhsdiufhg iudshfg uihdsfgiu hdiusfhg iudshfg uhdsfug hdsiufh giudshfg iusdh giudsfhg iudfhsg iuhsigu hsfdui ghiusdfhg uidfgui hsdfiuh guidfhs giusdhfg iuhdsfguihdfgiuhfdsiuhguidfhguidshgiufdhgiudhfguifdgiu//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// dasuhfiuadshfiuadhfuisdahuf asdf //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ufw hfudsh fuisdh fiusdhfiusdhf iushdf iuds f</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-32" style="margin-left: 25%">
      <div class="w3-third">
        <p>Nikola Cokic</p>
            
        <p><img src="cokics.jpg" class="w3-round w3-margin-bottom" alt="Nikola Cokic" style="width:60%"></p>
       <p> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_cokic/" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-orange w3-border w3-hide-small "><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>_cokic</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-third" style="margin-right:  30%">
        <p>Marko Murganovic</p>
        <img src="murga1.jpg" class="w3-round w3-margin-bottom" alt="Marko Murganovic" style="width:60%; height:465px" >
        <p> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/murga_001/" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-orange w3-border w3-hide-small "><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>murga_001</a></p>

      </div>
      <div class="w3-third" id="tabela">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Shop banner -->
  <div class="w3-black" id="tour">
    <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px">
      <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">SHOP</h2>
      <p class="w3-opacity w3-center"><i></i></p><br>




<!----Ovde se namest ashop kasnije---->

      <ul class="w3-ul w3-border w3-white w3-text-grey">
        <li class="w3-padding"> <span class="w3-tag w3-red w3-margin-left"></span></li>
        <li class="w3-padding"> <span class="w3-tag w3-red w3-margin-left"></span></li>
        <li class="w3-padding"> <span class="w3-badge w3-right w3-margin-right"></span></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-32" style="margin:0 -16px">
        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
          <img src="/w3images/newyork.jpg" alt="Proizvod" style="width:100%; height: 500px" class="w3-hover-opacity">
          <div class="w3-container w3-white">
            <p><b>Proizvod</b></p>
            <p class="w3-opacity"></p>
            <p></p>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-margin-bottom" onclick="document.getElementById('ticketModal').style.display='block'">Naruci!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
          <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="Proizvod" style="width:100%; height: 500px" class="w3-hover-opacity">
          <div class="w3-container w3-white">
            <p><b>Proizvod</b></p>
            <p class="w3-opacity"></p>
            <p></p>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-margin-bottom" onclick="document.getElementById('ticketModal').style.display='block'">Naruci!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
          <img src="/w3images/sanfran.jpg" alt="Proizvod" style="width:100%; height: 500px" class="w3-hover-opacity">
          <div class="w3-container w3-white">
            <p><b>Proizvod</b></p>
            <p class="w3-opacity"></p>
            <p></p>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-margin-bottom" onclick="document.getElementById('ticketModal').style.display='block'">Naruci!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Shop modal -->
  <div id="ticketModal" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal w3-center w3-padding-32"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('ticketModal').style.display='none'" 
       class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge w3-display-topright">×</span>
        <h2 class="w3-wide"><i class="fa fa-suitcase w3-margin-right"></i>Naruci</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p><label><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></label></p>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Koliko?">
        <p><label><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Send To</label></p>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-teal w3-padding-16 w3-section w3-right">PLATI <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
        <button style="margin-left:7%" class="w3-button w3-red w3-section" onclick="document.getElementById('ticketModal').style.display='none'">Close <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
        <p class="w3-right">Need <a href="#" class="w3-text-blue">help?</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Kontakt -->
  <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px" id="contact">
    <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">KONTAKT</h2>
    <p class="w3-opacity w3-center"><i>Imas neku poruku? Ostavi je ovde!</i></p>
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-32">
      <div class="w3-col m6 w3-large w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="width:30px"></i>Negotin, Serbia<br>
        <i class="fa fa-phone" style="width:30px"></i> Phone: +381 ... ...<br>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" style="width:30px"> </i> Email: Dreamcarab@gmail.com<br>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col m6">
        <form action="/action_page.php" target="_blank">
          <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
            <div class="w3-half">
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Ime" required name="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half">
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="E-mail adresa" required name="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Poruka" required name="Message">
          <button class="w3-border w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">POSALJI</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- kraj -->
</div>

<!-- footer -->
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <h1>LINKOVI</h1>
  <h1><i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dream_car_ng/" class=" w3-hover-opacity"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH-qdkK4TvMV6KMrjkW0NDw"><i class="fa fa-youtube w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  </h1>
</div>


<script>
// Automatic Slideshow - change image every 4 seconds
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000);    
}

// Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else { 
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" i already tried adding this line and nothing changed

Comment: You need to learn about `media queries`, they are used to create reactive responses for a web page to different screen sizes. Once you learn it, you can update your website to be responsive easily.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn responsive web design, you can't just add the meta tag and expect your website to turn mobile friendly (I know, it's disappointing). You have to add media queries and use vh, vw, rem, and percents when necessary. Freecodecamp has a great course of responsive web design. Make sure you keep that meta tag, or otherwise media queries won't work on other devices.

And please make sure you search for an answer before posting a question, else you will get downvotes

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a few ways this can be done. I'll do my best to describe a few of them here but as @Love2Code said, you really need to learn responsive web design as there isn't a simple on/off switch you can add to do what you want.

The most basic way is to add a `@media` tag to your code. Here's an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
//updated styles for your mobile elements that will become active when the screen 
//is smaller than 1080px
}
```

I recommend putting this tag at the end of your code.

Another way of doing this is to make your website responsive by design through use of a smart CSS layout. My personal favorite are the `grid` and `flex` display methods. You can find some great examples of that [here](http://1linelayouts.glitch.me/).

Yet another method I would recommend in regards to fonts is to set your initial `font-size` to a default `px` amount inside the `body` tag of your CSS and then set the `font-size` of any following elements to a `em` value. An `em` value is simply a percent of the size of the default value (so a `font-size: 2em` would be 2 times larger than the default size). Then, you can simply adjust your default `font-size` in your `body` tag and the changes will be made seamlessly throughout your page. Here's an example:

```
body {
   font-size: 24px;
}
h1 {
   font-size: 3em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   body {
      font-size: calc(12px + 12 * ((100vw - 320px) / 1600));
      //this is a simple css calculation that will gradually adjust the font-size as the 
      //screen width changes between two points
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   body {
      font-size: 12px;
   }
}
```

To explain that `calc` above, here is the breakdown of that if you're interested.

```
font-size: calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
```

Lastly, I recommend adding a `viewport` meta tag to your HTML.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This will keep your content from being scaled, or zoomed out, by browsers on smaller screens. This is huge when it comes to making your own custom web CSS because the browser may override those without this tag.

These are some of the best tools for making a website responsive. However, I highly recommend checking out a course online as @Love2Code said. Self-teaching is great and can work in some cases but, at the bare minimum it's good to know something about what is going on so that when you have questions you can ask about specifics.

I hope that was helpful.