# Responsive site- without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I started learning html, and i have to create a site ( without js), this is my code:

```
https://codepen.io/marcin-panasiuk/pen/xxEreym
```

and i have to made this site responsive, like in this link :

```
https://www.figma.com/file/YglqfahKunKX59rnf4xL5Snc/Projekt-zaliczeniowy-%231?node-id=1%3A17
```

the thinner one is how this site should looks like on phones.
I cant use Bootstrap.
Any idea how to start this?

Comment: Hi, I have answered your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363172/how-can-i-make-my-website-look-better-on-mobile/65363244#65363244

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. SO is for specific coding issues, not conceptionals or opinion based questions. Also always include a minimal reproduciable code snippet directly here. A link to a codepen, fiddle etc. is no acceptable as it provides no further use for other users.

Comment: Your question is not of the nature that someone at this site can really give you an answer for, it will likely get closed for a lack of focused content. However, one of the main things about building a dynamic media site would be media queries in your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

i had a look at your source code and your website
you can make your website responsive Bootstrap by  using  the below query

```css
 /* CSS file   */ 
  
  @media screen and (min-width:400px) {
   
    .tagname{ /* tag-properties here*/ 
      }
      
     
   }
```

and you can link this in your HTML page by using

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: px)" href="#">
```

for  optimisation

and try to write separate CSS files for each device you're using. This makes debugging easier and faster
furthermore reduce size of CSS files used

and  check out the following tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)